# Scanning for input without storing the values in a variable

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

I'm declaring a 2d Array with 100 rows and columns. Im trying to get the user to dictate the numbers that go into the array. Im supposed to store the values without storing them in a variable. This is what I have so far but I don't think this is correct

```
 public static void main(String[] args) 
{

    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int [][] nums = new int[100][100];
    int digits;

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; ++i)
    {

        int[scan.nextInt()][scan.nextInt()];

    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "store the values without storing them in a variable"? Are you going to store them in an array?

Comment: I mean scan for the input without storing the value. I dont know if this does not make sense. This is part of my assignment but this is what I dont undertand but thats what I have to do.

Comment: `int[scan.nextInt()][scan.nextInt()];`  What is that supposed to mean? Can you spell out your intent?

Comment: What directions does your *user* give? Does s/he just tells you numbers and you can put them anywhere in the array at your discretion?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use nested `for` loops for a 2-d array (one for rows and one for columns):

```
for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; ++i)
     for (int j = 0; j < nums[i].length; ++j)
{

    nums[i][j] = scan.nextInt();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, first of all, you are dealing with a two dimensional array, so you will need two loops, one for the rows and the other for the colums.

```
for(int i=0; i<100; i++)
 {
     for(int j=0;j<100;j++)
        {
               nums[i][j] = scan.nextInt();
        }
}
```

This syntax - `int[scan.nextInt()][scan.nextInt()];` is not even legal.

Comment: Well, try it then if you think it's legal! :)

Comment: Works just fine. Again, it's a bad idea as there is no bounds checking, but it's perfectly legal syntax.

Comment: It's not! I checked it myself!

Comment: To be clear, `nums[scan.nextInt()][scan.nextInt()]` is legal as long as you do something with it, like `nums[scan.nextInt()][scan.nextInt()] = 5;`.

Comment: Yes, but as you can see, that's not what the OP had in his post.